# How to make an array out of common column values?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table **A** that looks like this:

```
|   title     | rating |
|-------------|--------|
|  predator   |   17   |
| tomb raider |   22   |
|  predator   |   18   |
|     ...     |  ...   |
|  predator   |   19   |
| tomb raider |   23   |
```

and another table **B** that looks like this:

```
|   title     | rating |
|-------------|--------|
|  predator   |   31   |
| tomb raider |   41   |
|  predator   |   32   |
|     ...     |  ...   |
|  predator   |   19   |
| tomb raider |   23   |
```

How can I create the following table with ratings from all movies for A and B, where if a rating doesn't exist in the other table it shows `NULL` else it shows the rating?

I have figured out how to find what should be `NULL` but I cant figure how to make the array. The following table has only 2 rows, 1 for predator and 1 for tomb raider. The rest is nested.

```
|   title     | rating A | rating B |
|-------------|----------|----------|
|  predator   |    17    |   NULL   |
|             |    18    |   NULL   |
|             |    19    |    19    |
|             |   NULL   |    31    |
|             |   NULL   |    32    |
|             |   ...    |   ...    |
| tomb raider |    22    |   NULL   |
|             |    23    |    23    |
|             |   NULL   |    41    |
|             |   ...    |   ...    |
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick was doing a `GROUP BY COALESCE()` and then  `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT())`:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *, fhoffa.x.int(LOG(word_count)) cc
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
  WHERE corpus IN ('sonnets', 'kinghenryviii')
  AND word LIKE 'a%'
  AND word_count > 10
)

SELECT word, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a,b)) ratings
FROM (
  SELECT word, MAX(a) a, MAX(b) b
  FROM (
    SELECT word
      , IF(corpus='sonnets', cc, null) a
      , IF(corpus='kinghenryviii', cc, null) b
    FROM data
  )
  GROUP BY word, COALESCE(a,b)
)
GROUP BY word
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT title, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT ratingA, ratingB
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT rating FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT(ratingA, ratingB)) rating ORDER BY rating) 
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(ratingA) ratingA ON rating = ratingA
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(ratingB) ratingB ON rating = ratingB
  ) ratings
FROM (SELECT title, ARRAY_AGG(rating ORDER BY rating) AS ratingA FROM `project.dataset.tableA` GROUP BY title) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT title, ARRAY_AGG(rating ORDER BY rating) AS ratingB FROM `project.dataset.tableB` GROUP BY title) b
USING(title)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

[image]